# Calculating a duration in excel from date and time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have 2 columns in excel, each column includes a date and a time in the following format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm'. One is a start date/time, the other is an end date/time. The end date/time could be another day for example. Time is in 24hr clock.

Sample data: 18/12/2012 16:13 | 19/12/2012 01:21

Can anyone help with a formula which can look at each of these columns and produce a total minutes duration between the start time and end time.

I have tried a few already, but having the date in there as well is where I get stuck.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So for your example the number of minutes is 548? You can do a simple subtraction to get total hours/minutes, so if you have start time/date in A2 and end time/date in B2 this formula....

`=B2-A2`

with result cell formatted as [h]:mm will give you **9:08**

to get **548** just multiply by 1440 (number of minutes in a day), i.e.

`=(B2-A2)*1440`

format result cell as general

Comment: wow.. that seems to easy, but it works. Thank you!

Comment: No problem Chris - if it works as you want them please "accept" my answer - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

=INT(B1-A1)&" days "&TEXT(MOD(B1-A1,1),"hh "" hours ""mm"" minutes""")

which is an all singing and dancing, working days, minutes and seconds.

This assumes that the first time is in cell A1 and the later time is in cell B1

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for this.. I tried it, but at first it just said '0 days 0 hours 0 minutes' if i re-type the date/time manually again it then seems to work. Both times the format of the cell/data is 'custom' 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm' so no idea why it wasnt working (any ideas??)

Once i got it working its great, but but how do I show just minutes please?

Thanks

Comment: Strange, as it worked for me. I decided not to just minutes as Barry has already suggestsed. Unless it doesn't work for you?